Proxy Error The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server. The proxy server could not handle the request
I'm running a Laravel project using docker-compose and here's the docker-compose.yaml:
version: '3.7'
services:
  apis:
    ports:
       - "9000:80"
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./apis
  menu_service:
    ports:
      - "9001:80"
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./menu-service
  restaurant_service:
    ports:
       - "9002:80"
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./restaurant-service

And this is Dockerfile:
FROM php:8.3-apache


RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y \
libzip-dev \
libfreetype6-dev \
libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
libpng-dev && \
docker-php-ext-configure gd && \
docker-php-ext-install gd \
zip

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

COPY apis.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/

RUN a2ensite apis.conf
RUN service apache2 restart

COPY . /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
RUN composer self-update --2
RUN composer install
RUN composer dump-autoload

RUN php artisan key:generate

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

apis.conf :
Listen 9000

<VirtualHost *:9000>
   ServerName localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html

   <Directory /var/www/html>
       AllowOverride All
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

Also I added this to httpd.conf in the server:
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/>
</VirtualHost>

Everything is fine but I can't connect to the other containers and I tried to reach them by IP address of container but it wasn't possible. BTW, it works on my computer and the issue just is on the server.
Also this is the output of netstat:
$ netstat -tuln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9002            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44195         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::9002                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::9001                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN   

When I call the api using container's ip by curl I got this error:
 "message": "cURL error 28: Failed to connect to 192.168.96.2 port 80 after 133115 ms: Couldn't connect to server (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
Also if I call the api directly by curl -s localhost:9001/api/blahblah I got this message:
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access this resource.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.59 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 9001</address>
</body></html>

And eventually this is the message when I call the api by http://example.com/api/blahblah:
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request

Reason: Error reading from remote server


I forgot to copy the contents of public directory for menu_service and restaurant_service, which caused the error.
